# Bump Mapping on top of iPhone Camera

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, camera

I want to bump-map the cameras images with a fixed texture...

I found the following thread: 
[Bump Mapping on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649998/bump-mapping-on-the-iphone)

on general bump-mapping techniques. But they didn't really have examples or tutorials on how to do it.

Now , just in case, does anyone know about good tutorials on how to bump-map on the iphone or on how to modify the iPhone Camera feed with openGL?

PS: Finally ended up doing something different, i.e. [refracting my Image using the OpenGL ES 2.0 refract function](http://tacticadev.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/simulating-windows-with-refraction/).

Comment: People tend to use the term quite loosely — what's your definition of a bump map? Are you definitely asking about something that wouldn't work as a normal map, for example?

Comment: Well, I guess I figured the whole Bump Mapping myself, the Book iPhone 3D Programming helped though. The bigger problem now is how to add OpenGL Effects to camera outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding to your comment, to add OpenGL effects to camera outputs you need to use AVFoundation, which was introduced in iOS 4. That can be used to get a live feed of pixel data from the camera, which you can upload to OpenGL as a texture — allowing you to do whatever you want subsequently.

If you'll forgive me referencing an answer I've supplied in the past, basic stuff to start receiving a suitable buffer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469848/).

You'll receive CMSampleBuffers on a secondary thread in your delegate method:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
     didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
     fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

You can use `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer` to get a [CVImageBuffer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVImageBufferRef/Reference/reference.html) and from that use a combination of `CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress` `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress`, `CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow`, and possibly `CVPixelBufferGetWidth` and `CVPixelBufferGetHeight` to get at a C array of the pixels. In my testing across an iPhone 4 and an iPhone 3GS, the buffer has only ever come back tightly packed (so, no padding between lines), meaning that it can be uploaded immediately as GL_BGRA, since the APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 extension is supported on all iPhones to date.

From there you obviously need to figure out what to do in terms of vertex and fragment shaders, depending on whether you have a normal map, a bump map that you actually want to affect visible shape (and, if so, whether by vertex perturbance or by ray casting) or something else.